# Create an association from a string in unknown format (it's like JSON?)

Tags: associations

I am trying to parse a string. The string is similar with JSON, but it's not JSON, I don't know the format name of the string, so I have to parse it manually but not to use Import.

Is there any better way to parse this sort of string?

In:

```
s = "{\\n    TBDisplayMode = 1;\\n    TBDisplaySize = 1;\\n    \
TBItems =     (\\n        \
\"com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.notebook.back\",\\n        \
\"com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.notebook.style\",\\n        \
\"com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.notebook.alignment\",\\n        \
\"com.apple.hitoolbox.toolbar.fonts\",\\n        \
\"com.apple.hitoolbox.toolbar.flexiblespace\",\\n        \
\"com.apple.hitoolbox.toolbar.print\",\\n        \
\"com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.help\"\\n    );\\n}";
a = StringReplace[
    s, {"\\n" -> "", ";" -> ",", "=" -> "->", "(" -> "{", 
     ");" -> "}"}] // ToExpression // Association
```

Out:

```
<|TBDisplayMode -> 1, TBDisplaySize -> 1, 
 TBItems -> {"com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.notebook.back", 
   "com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.notebook.style", 
   "com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.notebook.alignment", 
   "com.apple.hitoolbox.toolbar.fonts", 
   "com.apple.hitoolbox.toolbar.flexiblespace", 
   "com.apple.hitoolbox.toolbar.print", 
   "com.wolfram.mathematica.toolbar.help"}|>
```

Comment: That's what I'd do, but I'm curious if anyone recognizes/understands the format.

Comment: In Mac OS, I got the string using the command, defaults read com.wolfram.Mathematica